# Is it normal for a website to return HTTP Code 200 for a Page not Found(404) Page?

Tags: java, standards

I was doing some testing with some sites (that I will not mention), and they are returning 200 code when they are page not found pages.  Is this against any web development standard?

This is the code that I am using to see the return code of a URL:

```
System.out.println(new String("getRespCode=" + urlConnection.getResponseCode() + ", HttpURLConnection=" + HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK + "\n"));
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is called a `Soft 404` or `False 404`. Wikipedia has a [detailled discussion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_404#Soft_404_errors). It is not allowed by any web standard (and I don't know of any argument *in favor*), but so is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an error on their side.  It may be possible too, that the 404 error was redirected to another page to display a better response, and that page is sending the 200.

Answer (score 1):

It is common, though incorrect. Search engines will believe they're visiting a valid page, for example

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is absolutely against standards.  Thats like your oil light coming on when you're running out of gas.

Unfortunately it is common; however, that does not imply that it is acceptable.

phihag left a good link, worth reading.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for true 404's your code (as far as I remember) would not execute, but yield a FileNotFoundException.